# Switching between #if #endif directives

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, plugins, resharper

I have a directive #if Silverlight, source code in this directive working only in reference(link) to the class. Those in real class, source code looks gray color.

Exists a way (re-Sharper or plugin) to hot-switch between the classes of assemblies? Now, I need close the class and re-open it again from another location, it is inconvenient

[image]

Comment: Mmm, maybe show us the code? Or are we supposed to guess the answer? :)

Comment: I'm using CSLA and this directive from it

Answer (score 0):

there is no direct way; as you have stated you need to close the class and open linked one.

Answer (score 0):

Like debug and release you could make (copy) your own configuration. In each configuration you can define custom directives.
Just define your own directive?
Then it is easy to switch betweens configurations.